# Missing table alias falls back to using only field name

Tags: java, sql, jooq

My tables

```
N
ID|T_ID
1|1
2|2

T
ID|NAME
1|T1
2|T2
```

Using the tables as follows

```
com.db.N N_TABLE = N.as("N_TABLE");
com.db.T T_TABLE = T.as("T_TABLE");
com.db.T T2_TABLE = T.as("T2_TABLE"); //Random alias, not used in query

SelectQuery selectQuery = create.selectQuery();
selectQuery.addFrom(N_TABLE);
selectQuery.addJoin(T_TABLE, JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, T_TABLE.ID.eq(N_TABLE.T_ID));

Result<Record> result = selectQuery.fetch();
for (Record record : result) {
  System.out.println(record.get(T2_TABLE.NAME));
}
```

It gives a ambiguity warning, but still gets the value even though alias is wrong. I would expect it to return "null", I guess it falls back to using only field name.

Any idea how should I use it to get "null" in case of a wrong alias?

**EDIT**

I'll try to provide a more concrete example

My table is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  username character varying(200) NOT NULL,
  last_name character varying(100),
  created_user_id bigint NOT NULL,
  modified_user_id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_user PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT user_username_key UNIQUE (username)
)
```

Data in tables

```
3;"admin";"admin";3;3
4;"test";"test";4;3
```

Code

```
//Input params
Long userId = 4L;
boolean includeModifiedUser = false;

User userTable = USER.as("userTable");
User modifiedUserTable = USER.as("modifiedUserTable");

SelectQuery selectQuery = create.selectQuery();
selectQuery.addFrom(userTable);

//In some cases I want to include the last modifier in the query
if (includeModifiedUser) {
    selectQuery.addJoin(modifiedUserTable, JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, modifiedUserTable.ID.eq(userTable.MODIFIED_USER_ID));
}

selectQuery.addConditions(userTable.ID.eq(userId));
Record record = selectQuery.fetchOne();

System.out.println(record.get(userTable.LAST_NAME)); //prints "test1"
System.out.println(record.get(modifiedUserTable.LAST_NAME)); //prints "test1", would expect null as modifiedUserTable is currently not joined
```

Tested on jooq 3.9.3 and 3.9.5

Comment: What is the exact warning? Also, are the two table descriptions really complete?

Comment: When I first wrote the question I also got `org.jooq.impl.Fields: Ambiguous match found for ...`, but could not reproduce it now. Issue itself still exists.

Comment: My guess is when it can't resolve the table then it falls back to only field comparison and results in retrieving wrong data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Works as designed

In SQL, there is no such thing as a qualified column name in a result set. Instead, a result set (like any other table) has a set of columns and each column has a name, which is described by jOOQ's `Field.getName()`. Now, "unfortunately", in top-level `SELECT` statements, you are allowed to have duplicate column names, in all SQL dialects, and also in jOOQ. This is useful when you join two tables and both tables have e.g. an `ID` column. That way, you don't have to rename each column just because an ambiguity arises.

If you do have duplicate column names in a table / result, jOOQ will apply the algorithm described in [`TableLike.field(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TableLike.html#field-org.jooq.Field-)

> This will return:
>
> - A field that is the same as the argument field (by identity comparison).
> - A field that is equal to the argument field (exact matching fully qualified name).
> - A field that is equal to the argument field (partially matching qualified name).
> - A field whose name is equal to the name of the argument field.
> - null otherwise.
>
> If several fields have the same name, the first one is returned and a warning is logged.

As you can see, the rationale here is that if there is no full or partial identity or qualified name equality between a field in the result set and the field you're looking up in the result set, then the field name as in `Field.getName()` is used to look up the field.

#### Side note on column match ambiguity

At first, you've mentioned that there was an *"ambiguous match"* warning in the logs, which then disappeared. That warning is there to indicate that two columns go by the same `Field.getName()`, but neither of them is an "exact" match as described before. In that case, you will get the first column as a match (for historic reasons), and that warning, because that might not be what you wanted to do.